# Manual uninstall of Docker Desktop on Windows?

Tags: windows, docker, installation, uninstallation, docker-desktop

I tried uninstalling Docker Desktop in the traditional way (Control Panel -> Programs -> Programs and Features) but ran into some complications. I now have a bunch of Docker files scattered across my machine (e.g. in AppData/Roaming, the docker command still works, etc.) but it doesn't appear in Programs and Features any longer, so I can't try a traditional uninstall.

The Docker Desktop icon is still there, but when I click it I get a "Docker failed to initialize" error. When running the installer, it hangs. Is there a way to manually uninstall whatever Docker files I have left, the way the traditional uninstall would? Or just reset it somehow so I can use the application again?

Comment: Do a restart first after the traditional Uninstall

Comment: @KhnRzk I can't do a traditional uninstall any more, since it no longer shows in Programs and Features. I have restarted in the time since I tried the uninstall, to no avail.

Comment: Try uninstalling the Linux WSL 2 backend kernel too,

Comment: Could you explain what are your "complications"?